# installed font for notepad++ but it does show up

Tags: 20.04, notepad-plus-plus

I am using notepad++ on Ubuntu 20.04 I installed the inconsolata font https://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html by downloading and opening the `.otf` file then clicking on the install button. However, the font has not appeared in notepad++ for me to select. What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you're using Notepad++ that's a Windows application, it doesn't have a Linux port, so it might not show up becuase it's within Wine, and not the system.  You also might have to log out and back in again for the font to be picked up, or reboot if it was installed systemwide

Comment: @ThomasWard i have rebooted and it still does not show up. I can also confirm that double clicking on the .otf file continues to show that it has been installed. I installed notepad++ through Ubuntu Software and was wondering if that is the cause of the issue?